# Getting a No such file or directory error when trying to get JSON data from API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqAmC.jpg)

Why am I getting this error when I'm not even trying to access a file or directory? I'm simply trying to check if the date in the JSON matches the string I put in. I'm using Rails.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't like screenshot. Please write down your code, so we can help you :)

Comment: @BTL nobody likes screenshots of code or logs. They are unreadable, unsearchable and can't be copy-pasted by people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is line 22.
You wrote :

```
if covid_country['Date'] = `#{Date.yesterday.to_s}T00:00:00Z`
```

1. For comparison you need to use `==`
2. You should not use backticks in ruby to interpolate (that's javascript)

To fix you code you need to do :

```
if covid_country['Date'] == "#{Date.yesterday.to_s}T00:00:00Z"
```

Comment: could also use .eql?().  It's neater.

Comment: oh. my. god. thank you so much, man. also, duly noted on the screenshot thing. this is my first post in stackoverflow so i didn't know.